# Last Digit: Calculate how many times digit from 0 to 9 is the last digit of an element in the sequence

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

We are given two numbers **a** and **n**

Given the following sequence:

```
[a^1, a^2, a^3.....a^n-1, a^n]
```

Calculate how many times digit from 0 to 9 is the last digit of an element in the sequence

**Input**

> **a** = 2, **n** = 7

**Output**

```
[0:0,1:0,2:2,3:0,4:2,5:0,6:1,7:0,8:2,9:0]
```

Since the last digit of the sequence will be `[2,4,8,6,2,4,8]`

My approach was to make an array of **n**, `a[n]`, calculate the sequence and store in this array. Make another array of 10, o[10], where every element is 0.

Now from array `a[n]`, for every element, do `m=a[i]%10`, and the result of this will increment in the array `o[m]` array. Suppose, we do *64%10*, we get *4*. Now increment the element of the array at index *4*.

Is this the right approach? I am not able to code it.

Comment: You don't actually need to store the sequence, keeping track of the last digit counts will be sufficient.  Apart from that you seem to be on the right track.

Comment: Why are you not able to code it?  If you have a coding question, please post the code you've tried and let us know where you're having trouble.

Comment: P.S. If `n` is so large that you can't compute `a^n`, then keep in mind that in your sequence, as soon as you hit a number whose last digit equals `a%10`, the pattern will repeat because of the way modular arithmetic works.  But I wouldn't worry about that until you get the basic code correct first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're only interested in the last digit, only the last digit of `a` is relevant, because

```
(a * a) % 10 = ((a % 10) * (a % 10)) % 10
```

Besides, the last digits form a repeating pattern of length `1`, `2`, or `4`, depending on `a`. In particular:

- For `a % 5` is `0` or `1` (`0`, `1`, `5`, and `6`) the same digit repeats all the time (`0^n = 0` and `1^n = 1`).
- For `a % 5` is `-1` (`4` and `9`) you get an alternating pattern of `-1` and `1` (`mod 5`). In particular, for `4` both `4` and `6` occur `n/2` times. For `9`, this holds for `1` and `9`.
- For `a % 10` in  `[2, 8]` every digit in `[2, 4, 6, 8]` occurs `n / 4` times.
- For `a % 10` in `[3, 7]` every digit in `[1, 3, 7, 9]` occurs `n / 4` times.

In the last 3 cases there may be some remainder. For this you need to use a simple algorithm, which will need at most `10` steps. Therefore, this is a `O(1)` time algorithm (pseudocode):

```
if (a % 10 in [0, 1, 5, 6])
    return [a % 10: n]
else 
    if (a % 10 in [4, 9])
        c = n / 2
        r = n % 2
        counts = [a % 10: c, 10 - a % 10: c]
    else
        c = n / 4
        r = n % 4
        if (a % 2 == 0)
            counts = [2: c, 4: c, 6: c, 8: c]
        else
            counts = [1: c, 3: c, 7: c, 9: c]

    d = a % 10
    for i = 0; i < r; i++
        counts[d]++
        d = (d * a) % 10

    return counts
```

Comment: The original question used `^`, i.e. exponentiation.  It looks like your results are for *multiples* of the base, not *powers*.  The actual distributions are quite a bit different for powers (e.g. if `a%10==5` then *every* power ends in 5).

Comment: @ajb You're totally right. I got mixed up with multiplication and powers. I think my edit fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudocode:

```
for i in 1 to n
  v = a^i
  o[v % 10]++
end
```

Answer (score 0):

using System;
public class CandidateCode
{
    public static string lastdigit(int input1,int input2)
    {
        //Write code here
        int a=input1,n=input2;
        int[] num = new int[10];
        string output="";
        for(int i=0;i

Answer (score 0):

You can get last digit by

a1= Math.Pow(input1, input2);
b1 = a1 % 10;

Answer (score -1):

Last digit You are given two numbers.

Given the following sequence:

```
[a, a2, a3, … an-1, an]
```

calculate how many times each digit from 0 to 9 is the last digit of an element in the sequence.
Your program should accept a filename as an argument that contains the input. Every line of the input file contains a pair of integers `a` and `n`.

Input/Output Specifications

Examples For example, the following input:

```
a = 2, n=7
```

would produce the following output:

```
0 : 0, 1 : 0, 2 : 2,3 : 0 ,4 : 2, 5 : 0, 6 : 1 ,7 : 0 , 8 : 2 , 9 : 0
```

since the last digits of the sequence would be `[2, 4, 8, 6, 2, 4, 8]`.